# How to make swagger schema for file upload API in django-rest-framework using drf-yasg?

Tags: django, swagger, drf-yasg

I am not able to find any support for making a schema for the file upload API.
The Swagger UI must have a button allowing a tester to upload a file for testing purposes. I am using firebase as a database so serializers and models don't come into the picture. I am using only Django's rest framework.

I have looked at drf-yasg's documentation that suggests using Operation for file upload. But It is a very abstract and obscure documentation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make sure you specify the `parser_classes` in your view. By Default it's JSON parser which doesn't handle file uploads. Use either `MultiPartParser` or `FileUploadParser`

```py
class MyUploadView(CreateAPIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)
    ...

    @swagger_auto_schema(operation_description='Upload file...',)
    @action(detail=False, methods=['post'])
    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        # Code to handle file
```

Comment: Yes, but how do we create a schema for this in drf_yasg?

Comment: @ToughGuy, you should be able to add schema via providing your serializer via view's class attribute (`serializer_class`) or via `@swagger_auto_schema` decorator;

This answer has helped me. Should be marked as accepted imo.

Answer (score 3):

Here is working example from my project

```
from rest_framework import parsers, renderers, serializers, status
from rest_framework.generics import GenericAPIView
from rest_framework.response import Response


class ContactSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    resume = serializers.FileField()


class ContactView(GenericAPIView):
    throttle_classes = ()
    permission_classes = ()
    parser_classes = (parsers.FormParser, parsers.MultiPartParser, parsers.FileUploadParser)
    renderer_classes = (renderers.JSONRenderer,)
    serializer_class = ContactSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            data = serializer.validated_data
            resume = data["resume"]
            # resume.name - file name
            # resume.read() - file contens
            return Response({"success": "True"})
        return Response({'success': "False"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out this [issue](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/issues/600). You can find how to use *@swagger_auto_schema* to create something like this

[image]

Comment: I used the same but my request.FILES is not showing anything when i upload via swagger. If i use postman, its working  fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use @swagger_auto_schema and use the following manual_parameters to upload files `manual_parameters=[openapi.Parameter(name="file",in_=openapi.IN_FORM,type=openapi.TYPE_FILE,required=True,description="Document")]`